# Android: Preferences

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse, java

Проблемы с Preferences.
Есть 2 активности (класса). В одной ключ "number" равен 0,а в другой (в которой я работал с этим ключом) = 2.
(Я при запуске программы выгружаю ключи). Код одинаковый и в одинаковых местах (OnCreate), разные только имена переменных:

```
notes = getPreferences(MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            Editor ed = notes.edit();
        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(notes.getInt("number", 0)));
```

Comment: пару раз перечитал... какойто набор слов... в чем проблема?

Comment: В том,что в одной активности читает данные с ключа "number",а в другой нет.

Comment: ну короче, я ответил, берем общие преверенсы и читаем значение...

Comment: да и вообще где ты видел способ такой как ты делаешь... 

***ДОРОГИЕ ДРОНЧИКИ - УЧИТЕ МАТЧАСТЬ***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String val = prefs.getString("number", ""));
```